# how correctly execute query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, having

[**STRUCTURE TABLES AND ERROR WHEN EXECUTE QUERY ON SQLFIDDLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bd60dc/32)

QUERY:

```
SELECT 
            n.Type as Type,
            n.UserIdn as UserIdn,
            u.Username as Username,
            n.NewsIdn as NewsIdn,
            n.Header as Header,
            n.Text as Text,
            n.Tags as Tags,
            n.ImageLink as ImageLink,
            n.VideoLink as VideoLink,
            n.DateCreate as DateCreate,
            SUM(l.Type = 'up') as Uplikes, 
            SUM(l.Type = 'down') as Downlikes,
            (SUM(l.Type = 'up') - SUM(l.Type = 'down')) as SumLikes
        FROM News n 
            INNER JOIN Users u ON n.UserIdn = u.UserIdn 
            LEFT JOIN Likes l ON n.NewsIdn = l.NewsIdn
            WHERE SumLikes > 20 AND n.DateCreate < STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-03 14:17:43', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
        GROUP BY n.id
        ORDER by SumLikes DESC
```

When i use query i get error:

```
Unknown column 'SumLikes' in 'where clause'...
```

I know that error in 'SumLikes' but how correctly make sql query?

Tell me please how make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap it in a subquery

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 
    n.Type as Type,
    n.UserIdn as UserIdn,
    u.Username as Username,
    n.NewsIdn as NewsIdn,
    n.Header as Header,
    n.Text as Text,
    n.Tags as Tags,
    n.ImageLink as ImageLink,
    n.VideoLink as VideoLink,
    n.DateCreate as DateCreate,
    SUM(l.Type = 'up') as Uplikes, 
    SUM(l.Type = 'down') as Downlikes,
    (SUM(l.Type = 'up') - SUM(l.Type = 'down')) as SumLikes
FROM News n 
    INNER JOIN Users u ON n.UserIdn = u.UserIdn 
    LEFT JOIN Likes l ON n.NewsIdn = l.NewsIdn
    WHERE n.DateCreate < STR_TO_DATE('2014-01-03 14:17:43', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
GROUP BY n.id
) Sub
WHERE Sub.SumLikes > 20
ORDER by Sub.SumLikes DESC
```

Comment: or just change it back to  (SUM(l.Type = 'up') - SUM(l.Type = 'down'))

Answer (score 1):

You cant use aggregate fields like `sum()` in where clause, you shuld use `having`,

the end of your query could be like:

```
GROUP BY n.id
HAVING SumLikes > 20
ORDER by SumLikes DESC
```

ofcourse remove `SumLikes > 20` in your `where`.

Check this out for more information: [MySQL Extensions to GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html)

Answer (score 1):

When adding a column an alias, we need to address it diffrently.

Remove `SumLikes > 20`
and add an extra command after `GROUP BY`

Example:

```
HAVING SumLikes > 20
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    n.Type AS TYPE,
    n.UserIdn AS UserIdn,
    u.Username AS Username,
    n.NewsIdn AS NewsIdn,
    n.Header AS Header,
    n.Text AS TEXT,
    n.Tags AS Tags,
    n.ImageLink AS ImageLink,
    n.VideoLink AS VideoLink,
    n.DateCreate AS DateCreate,
    SUM(l.Type = 'up') AS Uplikes, 
    SUM(l.Type = 'down') AS Downlikes,
    (SUM(l.Type = 'up') - SUM(l.Type = 'down')) AS SumLikes
FROM News n 
INNER JOIN Users u ON n.UserIdn = u.UserIdn 
LEFT JOIN Likes l ON n.NewsIdn = l.NewsIdn
WHERE n.DateCreate < '2014-01-03 14:17:43'
GROUP BY n.id HAVING SumLikes > 20 
ORDER BY SumLikes DESC
```